# Unpacking the data structure returned by Cake PHP's compact(...) function

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm working on the front-end of a Cake PHP project that has its back-end finished with a basic/half-implemented front-end on top.

In the a controller class I came across this:

```
$arr1 = $this->SomeModel->Data1FromDB->find('list');
$arr2 = $this->SomeModel->Data2FromDB->find('list');
$arr3 = $this->SomeModel->Data3FromDB->find('list')
```

`$this->set(compact('arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3'));`

and I want to somehow unpack what has been sent to the view.  Does anyone know how you're meant to process this data structure?

Thanks very much :).

Comment: Just a heads up, compact() is a native PHP function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to just access the variables by their names arr1, arr2, arr3 in your view. [`compact()`](https://www.php.net/compact) just creates an array like:

```
array('arr1' => $arr1, 'arr2' => $arr2, 'arr3' => $arr3)
```

Answer (score 3):

in this case compact is being used as a quick way to set many variable to the view in one statement.  You can access these directly the same as any other variable you would set to the view.

`<?php pr($arr1);?>`

`<?php pr($arr2);?>`

`<?php pr($arr3);?>`